# using dup2 and execv to get folder content in C

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe, dup

I wrote a program to use ls command in Linux terminal to read the content of the folder and write the text from ls to the screen with my C program. Here's the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int pipe_ends[2];
    if(pipe(pipe_ends)) 
    {
        printf("Could not create pipe\n");
        return -1;
    }
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(!pid)
    {
        dup2(pipe_ends[0],1);
        char* args[3];
        args[0] = "/bin/ls";
        args[1] = "-l";
        args[2] = NULL;
        execv("/bin/ls",args);
        printf("something went wrong\n");
    }

    char buff[10240];
    int count = read(pipe_ends[1],buff,10240);
    buff[count] = '\0';
    printf("here goes nothing......\n");
    printf("%s",buff);
    return 0;   
}
```

The output I get for this program is:

```
here goes nothing......
od@od-Inspiron-N5110:~/Documents/work/new/CO/project1$ /bin/ls: write error: Bad file descriptor

od@od-Inspiron-N5110:~/Documents/work/new/CO/project1$
```

It seems that reading has been done before writing. But I thought read is blocking. Please help me to find the error here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) and [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)? This could avoid you the useless `fork` of an `/bin/ls` ! Also notice that Linux have *directories* (not folders). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't do that because I'm doing an exercise here and am not supposed to use them. Thank you I'll use the term directory from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had three problems:

1. From the manpage: *The array `pipefd` is used to return two file descriptors referring to the ends of the pipe. `pipefd[0]` refers to the read end of the pipe. `pipefd[1]` refers to the write end of the pipe.* You were using `pipefd[0]` to write and `pipefd[1]` to read. That won't work. This was the root cause of the `EBADF` (bad file descriptor) error. If you want bidirectionality, use `socketpair()`
2. When you `fork()`, you need to close the file descriptors you don't need. That's the other end of the pipe.
3. I believe you should `close()` an fd before you `dup2` over it, though the man page is not explicit. In this case `close()` the existing `STDOUT` before you use `dup2()`.

Here is an amended version that works (minimal amendments made to get it working annotated with comments, there is more you could do to make it perfect):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main ()
{
  int pipe_ends[2];
  if (pipe (pipe_ends))
    {
      printf ("Could not create pipe\n");
      return -1;
    }
  pid_t pid = fork ();
  if (pid < 0)
    {
      perror ("fork");
      exit (1);
    }
  if (!pid)
    {
      close (1); /* close previous stdout */
      /* dup write end of pipe */
      dup2 (pipe_ends[1], 1);
      /* close read end */
      close (pipe_ends[0]);
      char *args[3];
      args[0] = "/bin/ls";
      args[1] = "-l";
      args[2] = NULL;
      execv ("/bin/ls", args);
      printf ("something went wrong\n");
    }

  close (pipe_ends[1]); /* close write end of pipe */

  char buff[10240];
  int count = read (pipe_ends[0], buff, 10240);
  buff[count] = '\0';
  printf ("here goes nothing......\n");
  printf ("%s", buff);
  return 0;
}
```

And the proof of the pudding:

```
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so$ ./p
here goes nothing......
total 32
-rwxrwxr-x 1 amb amb 8889 Jan 19 09:19 p
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amb amb  853 Jan 19 09:19 p.c
-rwxrwxr-x 1 amb amb 8456 Jan 18 20:47 test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amb amb  243 Jan 18 20:47 test.c
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to close the unused ends of your pipes — especially the write end of the pipe in the parent process since the `read()` in the parent will not get EOF while the parent has the write end of the pipe still open.  Also, you need to read from the read end of the pipe (`pipe_ends[0]`), and duplicate the write end of the pipe to the standard output of `ls`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pipe_ends[2];
    if (pipe(pipe_ends))
    {
        printf("Could not create pipe\n");
        return -1;
    }
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(pipe_ends[1], 1);
        close(pipe_ends[0]);
        close(pipe_ends[1]);
        char *args[3];
        args[0] = "/bin/ls";
        args[1] = "-l";
        args[2] = NULL;
        execv("/bin/ls", args);
        printf("something went wrong\n");
        return 1;
    }

    close(pipe_ends[1]);
    char buff[10240];
    int count = read(pipe_ends[0], buff, 10240);
    buff[count] = '\0';
    printf("here goes nothing (count = %d)......\n", count);
    printf("%s", buff);
    return 0;
}
```

The code should be more consistent about error reporting (sometimes it uses `printf()` to write to standard output; sometimes, it uses `perror()` to write to standard error), and exiting (sometimes using `return -1;`, sometimes using `exit(1);` — and I added a `return 1;` to ensure that the child process doesn't end up reading stuff if it fails to execute `ls`).

Comment: @UthpalaHerath: you were trying to make `ls` write on the read end of the pipe, and trying to make your program read on the write end of the pipe.  The code should now work.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. I was under the impression any end can read or write all this time. MY lecture notes does not mention this. :)